# Meaning of "how" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, questions

I have a question about the meaning of this sentence.

"I can see how artificial chemicals in sodas are not really good for me"

Does this mean "I can see how bad they are for me"? (used for emphasis) or "I can see how they have a bad effect on me"? (in what way, or by what methods)

Or could it be used either way?

Comment: Not the 'to what extent' sense you suggest. 'In what way/s, for what reasons ...'. Even, as BillJ suggests, just as a colloquial replacement for 'that'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How" here refers to what qualities of the artificial chemicals cause sodas containing them not to be really good to drink.

Perhaps this is a clearer example: Initial question - "How did you know I was in London last week?" "Well, Harold saw you there, and he posted it on Facebook, and Diane saw his post and mentioned it to me yesterday at yoga." "OK, now I can see how you knew I was in London last week."

Likewise, start with the question "How are artificial chemicals in soda not really good for me?" = "How do artificial chemicals harm one's health?" After receiving an explanation: "OK, now I understand how artificial chemicals harm one's health. I can see how they are not really good for me."

Answer (score 2):

> *I can see **how** artificial chemicals in sodas are not really good for*
>   *me*.

I'd take this "how" as a subordinator used in informal style.

It's used here without any trace of its usual manner or degree meaning, so it seems reasonable to say that it is no longer an interrogative word, and best reanalysed as a subordinator, a variant of "that":

*I can see **that** artificial chemicals in sodas are not really good for me*